# passing value from a page into inline dialog oracle apex

Tags: parameter-passing, oracle-apex

I would like to create an inline dialog.
In this inline dialog I want to start a search with the entries I made on the same site. I want to pass these entries to the inline dialog to start the search.
My question is, is it possible to pass parameters when creating an inline dialog.
Usually I always used a modal dialog for this.

Comment: Have you read this blog ? https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/

Comment: Hey thank you for the reference. I read through and it appears that this would solve my problem. I wanted to try the second input method, but I am not quite sure how I can create a dynamic action that passes the two parameters. I made a copy of the two page items (the ones I want to submit) in the inline dialog page and used the procedure apex_util.set_session_state('P1_INPUT_VALUE',:P1_INPUT_VALUE_DIALOG); in the dynamic action. However i am not sure if this is the common way to pass parameters

Comment: Sure it is. I would think you'd use ```apex_util.set_session_state('P2_INPUT_VALUE',:P1_INPUT_VALUE_DIALOG)``` instead - you want to set an item on the dialog page (P2) to a value in the calling page (P1).

Comment: Exactly I want to put an element of the page into the element of the calling dialog page.

Comment: Ok I see, that he uses two pages, so actually it is not an inline dialog.

Comment: An inline dialog is just a region on the same page so  have access to the page item values - why would you need to pass them ?

Comment: In the inline dialog I use a search function to get the email of the user, in this function I pass the values of the page items firstname and lastname (which I enter outside the inline dialog on the same page). However the values are not set and so the function can not execute.

Comment: Could you create a test case on apex.oracle.com ? I'm happy to take a look and see if I can help (workspace SO_HELP, username/pwd SO_70063696/SO_70063696)